# Getting Old data when using shared preference in Android error?

Tags: android

I am getting Sharedpreference value in multiple activity, Sometimes i am getting old value from shared preferences in android, i have created my own preference file to store loginid/pass etc.
what will be the possible causes of error????

Here i am creating code

```
public void openPref() {

    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("abc",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

**For setting and getting function**

```
public String getValue(String key, String defaultValue) {
        openPref();
        String result = sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);

        if (result != null)
            result = decrypt(key, result);

        sharedPreferences = null;
        return result;
    }

    public void setValue(String key, String value) {
        if (value != null)
            value = encrypt(key, value);

        openPref();
        Editor prefsPrivateEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        prefsPrivateEditor.putString(key, value);
        prefsPrivateEditor.commit();
        prefsPrivateEditor = null;
        sharedPreferences = null;
    }
```

**For Setting value**

```
Pref objPref = new Pref(getApplicationContext());
objPref.setValue(Pref.abc, 'abc');
```

**For getting value**

```
Pref objPref = new Pref(getApplicationContext());
objPref.getValue(Pref.abc, null)
```

**Problem**

I am settting abc value from two different activity but,
every thing works well but sometime it get old value suddenly in my android application.

Comment: do you always call editor.commit()?

Comment: @nikis yes, but where old value is going to stored??

Comment: SharedPreferences stores data in <key, value> pair. So for particular key the value gets overwrite. NO way to get old data from SharedPreferences once its overwritten.

Comment: please post some code to identify error..

Comment: what is your need ? storing actual data ? or storing all data (no overrides)

Answer (score 0):

Your sharedPreferences object is old. Each time you need to get a data from it initialise it again

```
  sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("abc",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

then try to get data. Since the data is change from other activity, you need to get it again.

Comment: Hi eluleci , every time we are creating sharedpreferences (openPref();)